# Java - Writing file location to Properties file

Tags: java, properties

I'm writing the **FILEPATH** parameter into the properties file like below..

```
String newFilePath = txtFilepath.getText();
Properties prop = new Properties();
java.io.File propFile = new File("src/com/app/tool/properties/settings.properties");
prop.setProperty("FILEPATH", newFilePath);
System.out.println("newFilePath "+newFilePath);
   try {
     prop.store(new FileOutputStream(propFile), "New File location");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The Filepath is  **D:\filelog.txt**

While writing, the console prints like..

```
newFilePath D:\filelog.txt
```

But when I open the properties file, content is like..

```
FILEPATH=D\:\\filelog.txt.
```

Anyone suggest me , what I'm really m(i)essing here ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call `prop.get("FILEPATH")`. You will see that you get back "D:\filelog.txt", just as you put it in.

Comment: Oh..!I found out that mistake.I'm using ResourceBundle to get the string value from properties file. Anyway thanks for pointing out this.Now all is fine.

Answer (score 2):

In a properties file, `:` has a meaning.

```
key = value
key: value
```

both are valid. Hence, it has to be escaped while writing to a properties file. Even `\` needs escaping. But when you display them on the console, the escaping is identified, and the values are shown properly.

If you see the docs of [store()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store%28java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) method of the `Properties` class

> Every entry in this Properties table is written out, one per line. For
>   each entry the key string is written, then an ASCII =, then the
>   associated element string. Each character of the key and element
>   strings is examined to see whether it should be rendered as an escape
>   sequence. The ASCII characters \, tab, form feed, newline, and
>   carriage return are written as \, \t, \f \n, and \r, respectively.
>   Characters less than \u0020 and characters greater than \u007E are
>   written as \uxxxx for the appropriate hexadecimal value xxxx. For the
>   key, all space characters are written with a preceding \ character.
>   For the element, leading space characters, but not embedded or
>   trailing space characters, are written with a preceding \ character.
>   The key and element characters #, !, =, and : are written with a
>   preceding backslash to ensure that they are properly loaded.

**Note:-** It shouldn't be a problem if you use `Properties` to read the properties file(it will handle the escaping), but if you read the properties file like a normal text file(you should never do it unless you're out of your mind), then it'll be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your information. So it means that saving file locations in properties file are not an encouraged behavior.Or still you can save in properties file and while accessing the location we've to replace the  \: to : and process further.?

Comment: They can be. You just saved them. Just that in the properties file, the `:` will be escaped, but that shouldn't be a problem for us, as long as your use `Properties` to read and write your `.properties` file.

Answer (score 0):

Backslash `\` is an escape character that is silently dropped in not followed by another `\`

Colon `:` is a special character that must by escaped with `\`.

Check docs at

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_properties.html